# Determining the acid dissociation constant change with temperature in sparkling water

Tags: ph, temperature

I already have the different values of pH at the different temperatures, but what I'm trying to figure out is obtaining the acid dissociation constant using these pH values. Is there a way I can do that without having the initial and final concentrations of CO2 in the sparkling water or would I have to do an extra step?

Comment: Check out pKa table?